# How to add an Angular 2 App as a view in Express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, server

I'm making an app in Angular 2 that needs to get data from a script which would run on the server. In order to do this, I'm trying to add my already existing Angular app as a view to an express application as is done [here](https://medium.com/cyrusite-chatter/building-an-express-node-js-app-with-angular-2-and-the-twitter-api-4eebd06fecff#.gypr9totv). I followed the instructions outlined in the tutorial for initial set up of the folder structure, but the tutorial didn't go over how to actual connect the Angular and express apps so that they would both be run together when `npm start` is used.

I then found another post which suggested to use the [express/angular generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express-angular) which I ended up installing which produced this package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "support-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.0.0",
    "ejs": "~0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect-livereload": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.11",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.11"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start test\\karma.conf.js"
  }
}
```

Despite the package being intended to provide the setup for Angular on top of Express, this file is only set up for express and not Angular. **What is the official way to go about setting up a Angular 2 project within Express?**

Answer (score 1):

I bet the official way is using angular universal. Allows you to mitigate SEO issues with one page apps. https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: Is there any other way to do setup a preexisting angular app with an express app?